# openni_tracker has problem opening database/parameter File

Tags: ros, kinect, openi-tracker, parameter, parameter-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to use the openni_launch and openni_tracker packages. I made a package called kinect_hmi and a launch file which launches both the openni_launch file and openni_track. When I tested this previously I could view he PointCloud2 data and the tf data in RVIZ. However, today when I started up the code I get the following error.

```
Error opening database/parameters file.
```

The point cloud data still shows up in RVIZ, but the skeleton tracking does not seem to be working. I tried starting roscore, openni_launch, and openni_tracker separately to see if my launch file was the problem but it didn't help. I have no idea why it isn't working all of the sudden.

Just in case here is my launch file

```
<launch>
  <include file="$(find kinect_hmi)/launch/camera_topics.launch" />
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="depth_to_camera_broadcaster" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 camera_link openni_depth_frame 100" />
  <node name="openni_tracker" pkg="openni_tracker" type="openni_tracker" respawn="true"/>
</launch>
```

The camera topics launch file is the following

```
<launch>
  <include file="$(find openni_launch)/launch/openni.launch" />
</launch>
```

I thought maybe that the parameter server wasn't running so I tried the `rosparam list` command. However, the command returns a long list of things so I'm assuming that the parameter server is running.

My question is: Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55950/openni_tracker-has-problem-opening-database/parameter-file/) by [rhololkeolke](https://answers.ros.org/users/1751/rhololkeolke/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2013-02-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Josch](https://answers.ros.org/users/3932/josch/) on 2013-03-04**:
Have you tried reinstalling the openni package? Maybe you can just start install.sh again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.
I have same problem, but i managed to fix it.
Problem is in primesense library. Some file don't have privileges.
U need go to:

> /usr/etc/primesense/Features_1_5_2

and set privileges to folder Data. I did it through nautilus and my problem was fixed.

Hope it will help you too.

---

Originally posted by [PNowak](https://answers.ros.org/users/4424/pnowak/) with karma: 26 on 2013-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rhololkeolke](https://answers.ros.org/users/1751/rhololkeolke/) on 2013-03-20**:
The system I'm developing on is erased each reboot. Unfortunately I rebooted before I could test this solution, but because rebooting (which would reset all file permissions to when they were working) fixed the problem I'm accepting this answer as correct.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2015-11-06**:
This answer fixed my error. Strange, I've been using the NITE packages for a long time, and I've never seen this error before. I wonder what caused it?